# MVC: Is it possible to override controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

A little background first as to why I need this. I am currently creating a CMS. If you imagine this CMS has a PageController which provides all the information a standard page needs, content, navigation etc.

Now the CMS can be amended for each client using it, and should a client require extra/different information in their pages I would like to override the default PageController with one tailored specifically for their needs.

This is what I have tried:

**Base controller**

```
namespace CMS.Core.Controllers {
    public class PageController : Controller {
        public virtual ActionResult DisplayHome() {
            // Logic
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Client specific controller**

```
namespace CMS.ClientCore.Controllers {
    public class PageController : Core.Controllers.PageController {
        public override ActionResult DisplayHome() {
            return Content("Client Home"); // Just for testing
        }
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
routes.MapRouteInLowercase(
    "Home",
    "",
    new { controller = "Page", action = "DisplayHome" },
    new[] { "CMS.Core.Controllers", "CMS.ClientCore.Controllers" }
);
```

**The Error**

> The request for 'Page' has found the following matching controllers:
> PCCMS.Core.Controllers.PageController
>
> PCCMS.ClientCore.Controllers.PageController

The cause of the error is obvious, so is there an alternative method to override a controller/controller action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are approaching the problem in the wrong way.

Create a `IContentProvider` which is used by the `PageController`, and let the content provider figure out what content the current customer needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see what you're saying and I'll restructure the controllers.